# Which method in AltBeacon lib converts beacon ID to Hex?

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

Before setting the beacon Id1, I choose the value let's say for instance `0x317a6e65657267`
However, when the beacon is detected and I try to get the Id1 using `beacon.getId1` the same Id changes to `00000000-0000-0000-0031-7a6e65657267`. I am looking for a method that can change the detected Id to HexString format.
Something like
`method(00000000-0000-0000-0031-7a6e65657267)` returns `0x317a6e65657267`

From the docs, I have tried `toHexString` and `Identifier.parse` methods but they didn't help.

**Currently**, I rely on string manipulation which I feel might not be the best approach.

Using **AltBeacon 2.12.4**

Edit: This is how I set the Beacon's Id1

```
//username is a String I get from EditText
//EditText only allows 15 characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ".", "-", "_"
//This is how I store the value
byte[] bytes = username.getBytes();
Identifier ALT_BEACON_USER_ID = Identifier.fromBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length, true);
String ALT_BEACON_ID_1 = ALT_BEACON_USER_ID.toString();
preferences.edit().putString(Constants.ALT_BEACON_ID_1_REF, ALT_BEACON_ID_1).apply();


//Next part is in the Activity where I advertise
String ALT_BEACON_ID_1 = sharedPreferences.getString(ALT_BEACON_ID_1_REF, INVALID);

Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
        .setId1(ALT_BEACON_ID_1)
        .setId2("1")
        .setId3("2")
        .setManufacturer(0x0118)
        .setTxPower(-59)
        .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
        .setBluetoothName(username)//username is fetched from sharedpreferences
        .build();

//This is how I get the beacon Id1
byte[] bytesBeaconId1 = beacon.getId1().toByteArrayOfSpecifiedEndianness(false);
```

Comment: How is it that you are "setting" the id1?  Is this on a transmitter?  And which beacon format are you using -- AltBeacon, iBeacon, Eddystone or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am transmitting via a device. My beacon format is `m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25` same as that on (AltBeacon website)[altbeacon.github.io]

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect how I am setting the Id1

Answer (score 0):

Understand that each beacon format has inherent sizes for each beacon identifier.  For the AltBeacon format, the first identifier is *always* 16 bytes and is by default depicted in a UUID format of 32 hex characters separated by dashes.

Even if you try to put fewer bytes into this identifier on a transmitter, a full 16 bytes will be transmitted.  If you do not care about all of these bytes and want to send fewer, it is up to you to add padding bytes on transmission and remove them on reception.  The library provides no methods to do this.

I suggest simply using the byte array at the bottom of your question and then:

- Write code to make a new byte array after striping off any leading zeroes
- Convert the stripped byte array to a string with `String username = new String(stripped bytes);`